# Changes to prestashop theme not reflecting

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop, theming

I have a Prestashop installation in which I have duplicated the original theme and I'm making changes to it. I have chosen the duplicate theme from the admin panel. The problem is that the theme is not reflecting any changes that I am making to the theme's smarty files. I have checked using firebug. I replaced the contents of global.css and it took away the styling from the site, but when I made changes to header.tpl, footer.tpl, etc. it does not reflect. Again I checked using Firebug: CSS is mine but HTML is not.

I am running PrestaShop v.1.4.6.2

Please help with this. I haven't the slightest idea as to what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste codes of what you had before and the changes that you made on the tpl files

Comment: `The problem is that the theme is not reflecting any changes that I am making to the theme's smarty files.` - Then your probably not editing the correct files. Make sure you have replaced the live files with your edited versions.

Comment: There's not much to paste, nothing changes at all. Even if I add random div's here and there. Changes to the DOCTYPE and HTML tags in header.tpl are also not reflecting. I am very sure I am editing the correct files, that was my first thought as well. Changes to global.css work though. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out.

Preferences -> Performance -> Force compile on, cache off

Comment: after this you can delete compile files in tools/smarty

Comment: Surprising it the fact that even deleting smarty cache didnt help much, if this option is not turned on.